# Could an amniote have tadpoles?

Tags: creature-design

Could an amniote have a tadpole stage like that of amphibians? The tadpole would be terrestrial as it hatches from a terrestrial egg, but it should still have tadpole traits. More specifically, the tadpole traits I'd like to keep would be:

- No legs
- No skeleton
- Distinct diet from adult (not milk)
- Normal-looking head with unique mouth
- Quick metamorphosis without a pupa

Could these traits work on a terrestrial amniote larva?

Comment: You can have a biologically plausible organism that does all the things you want, but it might not technically meet the criteria for an amniote. Call it a pseudo-marsupial, perhaps. Otherwise phylogeny recapitulates ontogeny, and all amniotes have a tadpole-like developmental stage they could (somehow)revert to, then reform an amphibian developmental pathway. Or amphibians could develop internal gestation, skipping the reptile-with-egg phase. Different evolution, regardless.

Comment: The new born young of mammals have a "distinct diet from adult(s)".

Comment: @DWKraus The tadpole stage of amniote embryos can't survive out of the egg

Comment: Yes, currently. But you could re-evolve a tadpole-like motile phase in an amniote that birthed large numbers of live offspring into a water environment like an amphibian (it's still a strategy, just not the ones amniotes currently use). That's why I said it might not technically be an amniote anymore.

Comment: Try these: https://animals.mom.com/amphibians-give-live-birth-6873.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A baby bird is close.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BppT2TW2fWk

[image: chick]

They are amniotes.  They are terrestrial.  They don't leave the nest and so they could get by with no legs and no skeleton.  They just stay there and beg.  They often have special mouths to attract feedings from the adults.  Items sought by the adults to feed their chicks are not necessarily what the adults eat - it is no stretch to think that the adults choose foods that will be good for the chick.

The chick had better metamorphose because it is going to need a skeleton, at least.  Legs help birds too.

Comment: “Legs help birds too”. Now I want to work out what a legless bird looks like! A snake with wings, perhaps??

Comment: @JoeBloggs - chimney swifts are close.  Their legs are minimal and they cannot walk or hop.  They do have feet, for hanging on.  https://nc.audubon.org/2011/09/chapters-host-chimney-swift-events

Answer (score 0):

The marsupials might have a solution.

This is a kangaroo new born baby.
[image]

The marsupials born in a very early state almost embrionic, with useless ears and eyes and as is supposable, not so developed skeleton and muscles.

They currently don't born from eggs because all the egg's functions are made internally inside of the mother, so they from the more primitive mammals got rid of the egg's shell, but still having a "yolk" inside the uterous.

So just that, some changes in the gestation times and search for a justification to expulse the shelless egg and is done.